# Can't insert guest addition CD image to get full screen on ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I can't figure out how to get my ubuntu virtual machine to become full screen and I've installed all of the guest additions. I keep getting an error when I go to, Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD Image. A pop up comes up and says "Unable to insert the virtual optical disk C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the machine. I've been trying that because everything I've seen just says to hit that and you will be able to go to View -> Auto-resize guest display to get full screen, but it is just greyed out for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try mounting the `.iso` manually?

From https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#mountingadditionsiso

> If you prefer to mount the Guest Additions manually, you can perform the following steps:
>
> Start the virtual machine in which you have installed Windows.
>
> Select Optical Drives from the Devices menu in the virtual machine's menu bar and then Choose/Create a Disk Image. This displays the Virtual Media Manager, described in Section 5.3, “The Virtual Media Manager”.
>
> In the Virtual Media Manager, click Add and browse your host file system for the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso file.
>
> On a Windows host, this file is in the Oracle VM VirtualBox installation directory, usually in C:\Program files\Oracle\VirtualBox.
>
> On Mac OS X hosts, this file is in the application bundle of Oracle VM VirtualBox. Right-click on the Oracle VM VirtualBox icon in Finder and choose Show Package Contents. The file is located in the Contents/MacOS folder.
>
> On a Linux host, this file is in the additions folder where you installed Oracle VM VirtualBox, usually /opt/VirtualBox/.
>
> On Oracle Solaris hosts, this file is in the additions folder where you installed Oracle VM VirtualBox, usually /opt/VirtualBox.
>
> In the Virtual Media Manager, select the ISO file and click the Add button. This mounts the ISO file and presents it to your Windows guest as a CD-ROM.